# Filling in NaN values in a column depending values from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

For each missing rating value, if the number of reviews is less than 100 and installations is less than 50000, I have to remove the row. Instead, if the number of reviews is greater than/equal to 100 and installations is greater than/equal to 50000, I have to fill in the missing value with the average value (rounded to 2 decimal places) for the Category of that row.

my code right now for Review < 100 & Installs < 50000 is:

```
subset_Rating = Googleapps_df[(Googleapps_df['Reviews'] < 100) & (Googleapps_df['Installs'] < 50000)]
subset_Rating.dropna(subset=['Rating'])
```

my code right now for Review >= 100 & Installs >= 50000 is:

```
subset_Rating2 = Googleapps_df[(Googleapps_df['Reviews'] >= 100) & (Googleapps_df['Installs'] >= 50000)]
subset_Rating2.fillna(Googleapps_df['Rating'].mean()).round(2)
```

But the problem I am having is that it isn't updating my original data frame. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: *average value (rounded to 2 decimal places) for the Category of that row* do you mean there are more than 1 category value for each row?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mentioned the (Inplace = True) attribute, which helps to modify original data

Comment: Where would I add that in because when i try and add it i get errors?

Comment: inside fillna(..... ,   inplace = True) and dropna(....... ,     inplace = True)